# Contents of SQL export not executing properly with felixge/node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have created an export of a sql database (all tables and views) from MySQL Workbench. After removing the database drop/create lines, I am able to run the contents of the export file through the SQL engine to recreate the tables and views over and over again without any trouble.

However when I try to stuff the contents of the file through felixge/node-mysql I get syntax errors.

Is there a standard way of handling this pattern with node-mysql?

Attached is the entire contents of the SQL file that I'm trying to get node-mysql to execute on a database. It fails whether the database is empty or already has tables in it.

**SQL File:** http://pastebin.com/YjuDbyEK

**NODE CODE:**

```
var db = new mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'admin',
    database : 'nps',
    multipleStatements : true
});

//Check for the SQL upgrade file and stuff the contents through node-mysql
fs.exists(setting.NPS_loadFile, function(exists) {
    if(exists){
        fs.readFile(setting.NPS_loadFile, 'utf-8', function(err, sql) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Couldn't read " + setting.NPS_loadFile, red(err));
            }
            else {
                db.connect();
                db.query(sql,function(e,r){
                    if(e == null){
                        console.log(cyan('Database structure upgraded.'));
                    }else{
                        sendError(ws,"<h1>SQL Error during upgrade</h1>"+e,e);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }else{
        console.log("Couldn't read " + setting.NPS_loadFile, red(err));
    }
});
```

Comment: Works just fine for me. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Andrey, are you executing it through node-mysql?

Comment: yes. Tried both node-mysql nd node-mysql2

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. We made a mistake in the file being executed. Sorry for taking your time.